# Coxph long format issues errors

Tags: r, survival

I have my data in long format correctly yet when I run the coxph function:

```
tryu <- coxph(Surv(entry,exit,dead==1) ~ age, na.action=na.omit,data=finalmerge)
```

I get the following error:

Warning message:

```
In Surv(entry, exit, dead == 1) :
  Stop time must be > start time, NA created
```

But none of my exit times are larger than the entry times and none of them are missing? How can I get this to work??

Thanks

Comment: do you have a sample dataset to recreate your error and understand it ?

Comment: wouldn't you want ALL of your exit times to be larger than your entry times?  Also, try explicitly specifying your variables.  It may be trying to put exit into event, so `Surv(time=entry,time2=exit,...)`

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your data use `dput(head(mydata))`
You should use an interval and maybe you have an issue with the arguments :

```
interval <- exit - entry
event <- dead == 1
tryu <- coxph(Surv(time = interval,event = event) ~ age,
 na.action=na.omit,data=finalmerge)
```

Comment: Also, I apologize as I had meant all the stop times were larger than the start times so the error did not make sense but using this code as suggested above helps the issue.